# Best way to sort array based of different sets of data?

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-structures

```
var array = [{value:"13",type:"Fruit"},{value:"61",type:"Animal"},
             {value:"19",type:"Fruit"},{value:"71",type:"Animal"},
             {value:"12",type:"Fruit"},{value:"15",type:"Fruit"}, 
             {value:"11",type:"Plant"},{value:"10",type:"Fruit"}, 
             {value:"16",type:"Plant"}]
```

What is the best/optimized way to sort this array such that I get all elements of type Fruit first and then the elements of type Animal (by picking elements from end of array).

```
expectedOutput = [{value:"10",type:"Fruit"}, 
             {value:"15",type:"Fruit"},{value:"12",type:"Fruits"},
             {value:"19",type:"Fruit"},{value:"13",type:"Fruit"},
             {value:"71",type:"Animal"},{value:"61",type:"Animal"}, 
             {value:"16",type:"Plant"},{value:"11",type:"Plant"}]
```

Note:- I don't need to sort it Alphabetically. It must be sort depending upon the specific type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the order of the `type` properties in an array, then subtract the index of the `type` property when sorting to determine precedence:

```js
const order = ["Fruits", "Animal"]

var array = [{value:"13",type:"Fruit"},{value:"61",type:"Animal"},
             {value:"19",type:"Fruit"},{value:"71",type:"Animal"},
             {value:"12",type:"Fruit"},{value:"15",type:"Fruit"}] 

const sorted = array.sort((a,b) => order.indexOf(a.type) - order.indexOf(b.type))

console.log(sorted)
```